# b is an invalid keyword for max() error when solving Cryptopalls 1-3

Tags: python, encryption

So I've been stuck at the third challenge from the first set on cryptopalls. I feel like I've found a way for the scoring system, but can't get the print right as it says 'b is an invalid keyword for max()'. Python is not really my expertise so I might be overlooking something. Any tips?
The challenge:

[image: the challenge]

So far, this is the code I got:

```
hexstring= '1b37373331363f78151b7f2b783431333d78397828372d363c78373e783a393b3736'
unhexstring = bytes.fromhex(hexstring)

def xor(ciphertext, b):
    return bytes([x^b for x in ciphertext])

def score(data):
    amount=0

    commondata = b'This is a nice sentence for referal'[::-1]

    for i in data:
        if chr(i) not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&*(){.,=-_\t\n\r\x0b\x0c':
            return 0
        j = commondata.find(i)
        if j != -1:
            amount +=1
    return amount


print(xor(unhexstring, max(range(255), b =lambda h: score(xor(unhexstring, h)))))
```

Comment: Hi Hi and welcome. Please always make the title as descriptive as possible. You can leave out the language from the title though, as this is already covered by the language tag.

Comment: I think you want `xor(unhexstring, max(range(255), key =lambda h: score(xor(unhexstring, h))))`

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot!